# How do you properly read GeoTIFF files with d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geospatial, tiff

https://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/view.php?datasetId=MOD10C1_E_SNOW&date=2016-01-01

I downloaded the GeoTIFF raster image file and I'm looking at the documentation for reading geotiffs via d3

```
d3.request("snow_201601.tiff")
    .responseType("arraybuffer")
    .get(function(error, request) {
        if (error) throw error;
        var tiff = GeoTIFF.parse(request.response);
        var image = tiff.getImage();
        var rasters = image.readRasters();
        ...
}
```

But I am unable to actually read the rasters properly (rasters is `undefined`). How can I go about debugging this? Why is it so difficult to read TIFF files? I've tried a bunch of different tiff files and none of them had rasters that were able to be read in this manner.